# how to set mouse click event only on specific vertex in graphsharp?

Tags: c#, wpf, graph-sharp

I'm using graphsharp and  to display different pictures in different kinds of vertex, however I couldn't find a way to set only on specific type of vertex that display specific pictures mouse click event. I need only specific vertex to handle the event. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use directly without trigger... I use this on vertex context menu

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GraphSharp_Controls:VertexControl}">
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ContextMenuClick"/>
                    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an event handler using Style and bindings in WPF like this:

```
<Style>
   <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="[APropertyOfVertex]" Value="[YourValue]">
           <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Click_Handler" />
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Hope this help

Comment: I've tried this. triggers don't support event setters. I got an error while trying this